# Square a list of numbers and divide it by the mean of the list

Tags: haskell

I need to square a list of numbers and divide it by the mean of the list. So far I have got:

```
square :: Float -> Float
square x = x * x

s2 :: [Float] -> Float
s2 xs = map square  (map (\c -> c - mean) xs)
```

Any help would be really apreciated.

Comment: Please explain what is stopping you from completing your approach. What difficulties are you facing?

Comment: What does "square a list" mean? As you can see, `square` takes `Float`, not `[Float]`.

Comment: i can do it with simple functions using :map square (map(\c _. c - mean) [3,4,5]) sum $$ but cant get the sample to run in .hs program. Sorry I'm new to this. Only been doing it 4 week. P.S. I can't use recursion.

Comment: @symon Break this up into several functions.  Have one function that squares the list, have one function that calculates the mean of a list, have one function that subtracts a number from each element in the list, then you can start combining them.  You can then make a function that calculates the mean of the list _and_ subtracts that number from each element.  Then you can make a function that squares each element _and_ feeds it into the last function I described.

Comment: thats map square (map(\c -> c - mean)[3,4,5])

Comment: It may seem pedantic to make such small functions, but this can definitely help at the beginning.  Remember, functions are cheap in a functional language, so utilize them to an extreme, then you can start refactoring your code to make it more compact.  Get it working first, get it pretty second.

Comment: i have for mean: mean :: [Float] -> Float
mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)

Comment: square :: Float -> Float
square x = x * x

Comment: all thats fine its just the last bit : map square  (map (\c -> c - mean) []). I have named it square2, so when I square the list, square2 $$ will give me the correct anwser

Comment: @symon Could you add this code to your question?  Reading unformatted code in the comments is bad for the eyes.

Comment: Your task is confusing. I'd start with clarifying what "it" is in "divide it by the mean", and what "square the list" means. You might need to give different names to different lists - for example, perhaps, you mean "square each element of the list to get the list of squares and then divide each element of the list of squares by the mean of the original list".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
s2 :: [Float] -> Float
s2 xs = sum $ map ((/mean).(^2)) xs
  where mean= sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Test:

```
λ: s2 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, but I'll assume that you mean to divide the **sum** of the squares by the mean.  Simple version:

```
sumOfSquaresOverMean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
sumOfSquaresOverMean as = sum (map (^2) as) / mean as

mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
mean as = sum as / fromIntegral (length as)
```

This does have one weakness, which is that the list will be traversed three times.  Gabriel Gonzalez's ["Composable Streaming Folds"](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html) discusses one possible solution to this, but it's more advanced, so you may want to skip it for now.

Comment: +1 for the reference to Gonzalez. -1 for giving a straight-up answer to a homework question.

Comment: I still have to adapt it to fit correctly, and when the teacher gives you the completely wrong answer. Thank god he did.